# How to scrape email from 'websites using cloudflare' ? which gives [email protected]

Tags: email, website, screen-scraping

i am trying to scrape website and all of its content.
The website i am trying to scrape uses cloudflare, so if there are email addresses in the website, it gets obfuscated and it shows `[email protected]` if i try to scrape using `php simple_html_dom`

if i open that page in any Internet browser , i can see actual email address.

So how can i scrape actual email address ?

How can i make cloudflare think, that i am accessing site from browser and not from bot.?

Comment: "So how can i scrape actual email address ?" - You use the API provided the website to do this.  "How can i make cloudflare think, that i am accessing site from browser and not from bot?" - You do understand you are asking how to defeat the protections offered by Cloudflare right?

Comment: website doesn't provide API.

Comment: This means the website owner has taken extreme steps to prevent bots from scraping their website.